# PHP script not picking up variables through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a *sign_up.php* script pointing to POST variables like so:

```
include "index.php";

$first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
$last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Where `index.php` contains actual markup and ajax code like so:

```
<div id=form-div>
<form method=POST action="" >
First Name: <br> <input type=text name=first_name pattern="[a-z]{2,}" required /> <br> <br>
Last Name: <br> <input type=text name=last_name pattern="[a-z]{2,}" required /> <br> <br>
Email: <span id=emailReport></span> <br> <input type=email name=email id=email required /> <br> <br>
Password: <br> <input type=password name=password required pattern=".{6,}" title="Password must be six or more characters" /> <br> <br>
Confirm password: <br> <input type=password name=password required /> <br> <br>
<input type=submit value='sign up' />
</form>
</div>

<script>
    $('form input:last-child').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#hidden').load("sign_up.php"); // hidden is a display:none div on the same page
});
 </script>
```

However, the *sign_up.php* script eventually picks up no variables and returns notice level warnings undefined for all those fields. Is it impossible to pick the variables like that?

**PS:**
The sign_up.php script contains no output on its own but just processing details for the variables being expected from the included scripts.
**BONUS:**
The first two regex patterns fail to match two or more letters only. In fact it matches nothing whatsoever.

Comment: You're not sending any `POST` parameters when you call `.load()`.

Comment: Also, your braces aren't balanced in the Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I've fixed the braces. The exclusion was as a result of me pruning off scripts from the actual page. Does the `load` function require parameters? I thought that is only required for the `.ajax` method. Besides, my other script has an `include` which should pick up those variables while it runs no?

Comment: The parameters are optional, but where do you expect the `POST` data to come from if you don't supply them?

Comment: Where would the `include` get them from? Form fields are only sent automatically when you submit the form normally. If you use AJAX, you have to send the form parameters explicitly in the Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the form fields when you call `.load()`.

```
$("#hidden").load("sign_up.php", $("#form-div form").serialize());
```

Comment: I tried this. It still sends nothing though. What could I be missing? Does the waiting script need the `include` cos I omitted it?